# Definition of "hot" resistor when calculating RMS thermal voltage?

Tags: communication, physics

I am calculating the RMS thermal noise voltage of a "hot" resistor of a tutorial sheet for uni. I have used the standard Johnson–Nyquist formulas, but the answer sheet does not include the entire formula.

The equation I am using is

$$v_n = \sqrt{4 k_B T R \Delta f}$$

But the answer sheet omits the 4. Would this be because it is a hot resistor or a mistake on my worked solutions?

Also my research tells me that a hot resistor is just that, a resistor above 65 degrees Celsius, am I missing something here? Is there another meaning?

Comment: Okay worked out why I was getting a different answer, needed to divide by 2 - but i still don't know why they mentioned hot resistor or the significance behind it.

Comment: I'd guess that they're just calling it hot to call attention to the fact that you need to calculate the thermal noise. The alternative would be a cold resistor, in which case you could ignore the effect.

Comment: They are just saying " don't assume that the resistors are at room temperature". @WhatRoughBeast is wrong, you include the noise if it is significant compared to other noise, not because it is arbitrarily "hot " or "cold"  In fact a 100 C resistor is not a lot "hotter " than a 0C resistor (373 K vs 273 K).  Also resistors has temperature dependant values.

Comment: @placeholder - I don't believe I said anything about cold being at room temperature.

Comment: At one of the places I work, a "hot" resistor is any load above 20K. that's -253.15°C!

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast well you certainly are implying something, 100 C only increases johnson noise by ~ 17%.

Comment: @ConnorWolf exactly! and even at that level the JOhnson noise is still 20% of room temperature value.

Comment: @placeholder - Listen to Connor Wolf.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast exactly. Even a 20 K resistor can contribute significant noise.  You can't ignore it.

Comment: Sure you can. It all depends on your signal to noise ratio and the dynamic range your application requires.

Comment: okay so i am getting that a "hot" resistor was just to draw our attention to the idea that thermal noise is intrinsic to all resistors. But does anyone know why you would omit the 4 from the equation? Am i using it wrong?